# How to use FingerGestures plugin to handle pinch gesture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I pinch on the screen with both fingers moving, it worked, but with one finger touched but not moving while another moving, the pinch callback didn't invoke.
How could I make it work when I'm not moving both fingers?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question,I read FingerGestures source code,in PinchRecognizer.cs,I found this codes.

```
 protected override bool CanBegin( PinchGesture gesture, FingerGestures.IFingerList touches )
{
    if( !base.CanBegin( gesture, touches ) )
        return false;

    FingerGestures.Finger finger0 = touches[0];
    FingerGestures.Finger finger1 = touches[1];

    if( !FingerGestures.AllFingersMoving( finger0, finger1 ) )
        return false;

    if( !FingersMovedInOppositeDirections( finger0, finger1 ) )
        return false;

    float startGap = Vector2.SqrMagnitude( finger0.StartPosition - finger1.StartPosition );
    float curGap = Vector2.SqrMagnitude( finger0.Position - finger1.Position );

    if( FingerGestures.GetAdjustedPixelDistance( Mathf.Abs( startGap - curGap ) ) < ( MinDistance * MinDistance ) )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

I think this part means FingerGesture define it can only work for two fingers,you could try to remove it.

```
    if( !FingerGestures.AllFingersMoving( finger0, finger1 ) )
        return false;
```